# problems to shrink my ssd for an ubuntu partition

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, bitlocker

I want to install ubuntu as second OS beside win10 on my ssd.

First i tried to shrink my ssd in win10 with diskmgmt.msc.
i have 75GB free space on the hdd, but just can shrink it by 9gb, obviously not enough.
Also i saw, that diskmgmt.msc shows my c-drive as "File System: NTFS (Bitlocker Encrypted)". But my Bitlocker is deactivated.

so i tried to do it in ubuntu-live with gparted. Gparted only shows me "unknown" for free space and used space.

ofc the ubuntu installer doesn't allow me to shrink it enough too.

Maybe a useful information:
[image: see_screenshot_here]

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> manage-bde -status c:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.17134
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: [Windows]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 217,13 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100,0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:       None Found
```

I am not even sure if this Bitlocker status causes the problem that i can't shrink my ssd enough.

thank you in advance!

Comment: If you defragment the drive you may be able to shrink it more, but like you I don't know how BitLocker affects this.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news: While bitlocker is in status "Protection off", it is still there. This means, you can't shrink from outside the system. From inside the system you are at Microsoft's mercy - they think only 8 out of 217 GB should be freed.

The good news: 8G is more than enough for Ubuntu - I typically use root partitions of 8G even on Petabyte-scale storage servers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. while 8GB is enough for you, unfortunately it isn't enough for me. Ubuntu will be my main OS, so most files should be located in my Ubuntu partition. i do lots of coding, and after some time i surely need more than 8GB :(

Comment: 1)You can just disable HDD cryptography in Windows settings (just search for "bitlocker" and you will find it)... but before doing that, you have to backup your hdd bitlocker partition key (search on web, for example:https://www.howto-connect.com/get-bitlocker-recovery-key-cmd-windows-10/ ).

After that you can finally restart and boot from your linux live usb, and you will be able to access and resize windows partition, so you'll be able to install your linux distro.

Comment: 2)When your linux distro will be installed, if you want to bring cryptography in windows partition back, you will have to boot windows (NOT from linux grub bootloader, BUT selecting windows via bios boot options), and then enable hdd bitlocker cryptography back.

Finally restart, and when you'll try to boot windows you will be asked to write the bitlocker key, so write the key that you backupd.

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable HDD cryptography in Windows settings (just search for "bitlocker" and you will find it)... but before doing that, you have to backup your hdd bitlocker partition key (search on web, for example [look here](https://www.howto-connect.com/get-bitlocker-recovery-key-cmd-windows-10/)).

After that you can finally restart and boot from your linux live usb, and you will be able to access and resize windows partition, so you'll be able to install your linux distro.

When your linux distro will be installed, if you want to bring cryptography in windows partition back, you will have to boot windows (NOT from linux grub bootloader, BUT selecting windows via bios boot options), and then enable hdd bitlocker cryptography back.

Finally restart, and when you'll try to boot windows you will be asked to write the bitlocker key, so write the key that you backupd.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.